# Is finally block always ensured to run in the same Task (or execution context) with the try block?

Tags: c#, try-catch

I have some code run in a constructor of a class implementing `IDisposable` and another code run in the `Dispose` method. I would like to ensure that both code run in the same `Task` or execution context.

Behind the scene when using `using`, the code run in the constructor should run in `try` block whereas the code run in `Dispose` should run in the `finally` block. So the original concern now is to ensure that the code run in `try` and `finally` are always in the same `Task` or execution context. But I'm not sure if that's ensured by design?

```
try {
   //the execution context at the start here
   //should be the same with the context in the finally block below       
}
finally {

}
```

To make it clearer, please take a look at this code instead:

```
using(var o = new Scope()){
    //whatever code in here
}
```

The `Scope` class:

```
public class Scope : IDisposable {
    public Scope(){
        //run some code here (1)
    }
    public void Dispose(){
        //run some other code here (2)
    }
}
```

So I would like to ensure that (1) & (2) run in the same Task or context (actually the `AsyncLocal` is involved here, in the `Dispose` method I want to clear some values saved in `AsyncLocal`).

Comment: Depends on what type of `SynchonizationContext` you have, if any, and whether you use `ConfigureAwait(false)`, when running the `using`. If you are running on the a `SynchronizationContext` that does this, then it will be automatically marshalled back to the correct thread

Comment: In addition to what Charlieface said, be aware that for console apps there is no `SynchonizationContext` by default, so it's more difficult to ensure that you don't end up running on a different thread. However, if you're not using `async`/`await` then the issue won't arise (unless you're doing something with `Task.Run()` and continuations)

Comment: @MatthewWatson please take a look into what I updated (hope that it is made clearer). I don't know the flow of `try-finally` behind the scenes but I think whatever code used in the `try` block does not matter (because my first code already run in the constructor of `Scope` before). Looks like it all depends on the `finally` block. Thanks.

Comment: @Charlieface please take a look into my updated question, I hope that it will be clearer now. Thanks.

Comment: `//whatever code in here` is important. Does it have an `await`, and if so are you using `ConfigureAwait(false)`? What `SynchonizationContext` are you running under, if any? In other words are you working on a UI thread such as Winforms or WPF, or perhaps an ASP.Net thread, or is it just a console app? If you use `await` then the `AsyncLocal` will always work, as it stays with the continuation of your current method

Comment: @Charlieface usually if any async code is in there, it should be awaited. However it's kind of user code (not my code) so it's simply out of control. For what you asked, looks like the `finally` block just continues the execution as if it was written after the `try` block without any special handling? If that's how it flows, I can understand why using `ConfigureAwait(false)` may matter.